# is there an equivilent phpunit dataProvider functionality in ruby test-unit gem

Tags: ruby, testunit, dataprovider

I'm currently converting a whole bunch of acceptance tests from php into ruby and many of the tests use specific scenarios to test certain conditions.  We use @dataProvider a lot and my google foo can't find any information if this functionality exists in the test-unit gem.

As a work around I'm manually calling a supporting method to give me the required values to test against and putting the test scenarios in var.each{} loops.  It's not elegant but it works.  I'd still prefer to use the dataProvider route if it's available though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google foo is probably very good, however in Ruby something similar is called a fixture.

[Fixtures in Ruby Unit Tests](http://push.cx/2007/fixtures-in-ruby-unit-tests)